# React Native Navigation addListener via ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

So I'm running

```
        <App
            ref={nav => {
                this.navigator = nav;
                let self = this;
                if(nav) {
                    console.log("print nav");
                    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(nav.state.nav));
                    console.log("print nav");
                    nav.addEventListener('didBlur',
                        payload => {
                            //console.debug('didBlur', payload);
                            self.setState({
                                canBack: navigator.state.routes[navigator.state.index].index === 0
                            });
                        })
                }
            }}
        />
```

where `App` is generated by a `createAppContainer` call. I keep getting `undefined is not a function (near '...nav.addEventListener...')`. I also tried doing it in the `componentDidMount` of `App`'s parent with `this.navigation` but I got the same result. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Here's a demo: https://snack.expo.io/@aidanedwardsbu/refeventlistener

Edit: I posted an issue to `react-navigation`'s GitHub here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6590

Comment: check this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo I think that's for when you're inside app container, not outside